# glUnmapBuffer while keeping glMapBuffer memory valid as read-only

Tags: c++, c, opengl, pbo

Is it possible to `glUnmapBuffer` a `GL_STREAM_DRAW` pixel-buffer-object and still keep the data pointed to by the pointer returned previously by `glMapBuffer` **valid for read-only operations** using SSE 4.1 streaming loads?

If not, is there any technical reason for this? Or was this "feature" just left out?

Comment: I guess not. The [`map_buffer_range`](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/map_buffer_range.txt) extension (which is core in 3+) provides some more fine-grained control over mapping, but I don't think there is any way to guarantee valid memory after `glUnmapBuffer`. Interresting question, though.

Comment: Maybe some kind of OpenCL interop "hack" could do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of map and unmap is to say "I need a pointer to this." and "I'm finished using the pointer to this." That's what the functions do.

When you unmap a buffer, the driver is now free to:

1. Copy the data you wrote (if you wrote anything) to the buffer object, if the mapped pointer is not a direct pointer to that buffer.
2. Move the buffer object around in GPU memory, if the mapped pointer *is* a pointer to that object.

Remember: mapping a pointer does not *have* to return an actual pointer to that buffer. It simply returns a pointer that when read, will have the data stored in that buffer, and when written, the written bytes will be transferred into the buffer upon unmapping.

Furthermore, the only reason to do what you're suggesting is because you want to read the data in the buffer. Well, since you just mapped the buffer (presumably for writing, or else you wouldn't have unmapped it), you know what's in it. If you needed CPU access to it, you should have just stored the data locally; you'll get a lot more reliable access to it that way.

And if you do another pixel transfer, reading from that pointer it means that OpenGL would have to execute a synchronization, because the whole point of PBO is asynchornous transfer. That is, when you execute `glReadPixels` or whatever, OpenGL can wait to actually finish this operation until you map the buffer or use `glGetBufferSubData`.

But if the buffer is mapped for reads, then OpenGL doesn't know when you're going to read from it (since it can't tell when you read from a pointer). So OpenGL can't guarantee the storage within it. In short: undefined behavior. You could get *anything* at that point.

So what you're talking about doesn't make sense.

Comment: The reason I want to do this is so that I can avoid making a copy of the data that is "unmapped" as it is a mayor bottleneck in my application. I need access to the data both on the GPU and CPU. And since I will never change the data after unmapping it I don't see any reason to why I couldn't hold the memory that OpenGL allocated and will read into the "unmapped" buffer.

Comment: @ronag: You could just be exchanging one bottleneck for another. Reading from a buffer is not like reading from CPU memory. Mapping makes no guarantees about where the memory lives, so every access could (theoretically) involve a transfer across your PCIe bus. In any case, you can't. And OpenCL isn't going to help you either. You can't use a buffer while it's mapped; that's the whole point of mapping it.

Comment: @ronag: The reason why you can't is explained in my answer: because OpenGL can *move the buffer*. It isn't in a fixed location. OpenGL is free to move buffers around in GPU memory as it wishes. That's why you need special commands to map them, and that's why you can't actually use a buffer that's currently mapped for anything.

Comment: Just found the AMD_pinned_memory which seems to enable what I want to do.

Comment: @ronag: If by "what you want to do", you mean "makes the buffer object's storage come from CPU memory" then yes that's true. Depending on what you use this buffer for, you may not like the performance you get on the GPU.

Comment: "Depending on what you use this buffer for, you may not like the performance you get on the GPU.". Please expand.